# Inhomogeneties in gravitational acceleration at the surface of the Earth.

Tags: gravity, acceleration

I am looking for data sets which clock the time and precise location of free falling bodies in a vacuum.  I have been told that the acceleration of gravity is not absolutely 100% uniform, and I would like to examine the data sets as to this question, particularly as to minute discrepancies. The more the better.  Any help in locating this raw data would be very appreciated.

Comment: For detailed work people generally do *not* use freely falling objects. I believe that pendulum devices are/were-in-the-pre-digital-era used for high precision.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93297/no-uncertainty-for-standard-gravitational-acceleration

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the data you're looking for exists; at least, not in any comprehensive form. Though there *are* some gravimeters that work by doing what you say - measuring the timing of an object in vacuum free fall - they are cumbersome and require the device to be fixed firmly in one spot. The gravimeters used in geoid surveys are usually *relative*, that is, they use springs or magnetic fields to measure the force on a test mass.

There are two reasons the strength of earth's gravitational field varies with location: the variation in altitude of the earth's surface and the variation of the density of the earth. The latter is the smaller and more interesting effect, and so most comprehensive geoid surveys are done by satellites that orbit at a fixed radius. As a result, these surveys are very expensive (not to mention very valuable for prospecting purposes) so you're probably not going to get access to most of the data out there without laying out some serious cash.

However, the European Space Agency recently completed a mission called the [Gravity Field and Steady-State Ocean Circulation Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Field_and_Steady-State_Ocean_Circulation_Explorer) (GOCE) that did a gravitational survey and some of their data is freely available for non-commercial purposes. You can register [here](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Observing_the_Earth/GOCE) and request access. I don't know what the form the data takes, i.e., how "raw" it is. An important note, though: satellites are in freefall, and hence the raw data of a mission like the GOCE is measurements of the graviational *gradient* from place to place. In other words, the variation of very small tidal forces. The relative strength of the gravitational field itself must be reconstructed from that based on the satellite's altitude.

Comment: What about GRACE?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Recovery_and_Climate_Experiment

See also my answer at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93297/no-uncertainty-for-standard-gravitational-acceleration/93298#93298

Comment: GRACE measures tidal acceleration too, just between two satellites it instead of within one. I don't know if their data is public.