How many significant figures does the speed of light have?
Since the speed of light (in a vacuum) is a constant, its number of significant figures should be infinite, right?
But if I were to say that the speed of light $= 3\times10^8$, would the number of significant figure be $1$?
Or, if I were to say that the speed of light $= 3.00\times 10^8$, the number of significant figures would be 3 now?
In general, if someone asks me “How many significant figures does the speed of light have?” what is the answer? Will it be different considering whether the value is specified or not? This is not about uncertainty but about how many significant figures does it have in general? Like if i were to just say 'c' so would it's significant figures be counted or not? If yes, then how many?

Note: significant figures are not infinite just because something is a constant. We only know the gravitational constant $G$ to within a certain number of significant digits because we can only measure gravity so precisely, whereas other constants like $c$ and $h$ are defined exactly - $299792458$ m/s and $6.62607015\times10^{-34}$ Js exactly, respectively.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92969/2451 and links therein.

That question is about uncertainty but i want to know the number of significant figures

@Hani They are more or less the same thing.

The meter and the second are defined to be the units of time such that $c = 299792458$ m/s exactly.  This number can be thought of as having an infinite number of significant figures, since it is an exact integer.
However, if you round the speed of light off to include fewer digits than this, then it is no longer exactly precise.  That means that in calculations, you should treat it as though it has as many significant digits as you used when you did the calculation.  So if you used $3.00 \times 10^8$ m/s, your final answer would be found by assuming that your value of $c$ has 3 significant figures and round your final answer accordingly.  If you used $2.9979 \times 10^8$ m/s in your calculations, then you would have to assume that your value of $c$ has 5 significant figures.  And so forth.

@Hani as an addendum to this: What I find is that if I/you actually have a situation where you need to use the speed of light ($299,792,458$ instead of $c$), it's better just to type out the whole number into your calculator than to round. The answer will be more exact and you can just specify that you're using the exact value of $c$ and forget about significant digits. If you don't want 299792458 appearing everywhere in your document, then just use $c$ as a placeholder and evaluate when necessary.

Also remember that if you use all those digits of c, you can no longer do things like assume the speed of light in air is the same as c.

Physical quantities don't have significant figures. Measurements have significant figures. If you perform a measurement of the speed of light, and you're confident that the first five digits of your measurement are informative, then that measurement has five significant figures, and when you report the value you got, that will have five significant figures. Significant figures are about your level of certainty, not about the physical thing you're measuring. If you say "speed of light=3.00×10^8", you're saying "I'm confident that the speed of light is around 3.00x10^8, with the error being less than 10^7." That's a statement about the error of your measurement, not about the speed of light itself. You're using the sequence of symbols "3.00×10^8" to represent the speed of light along with how precise you think you are, and it's that representation that has significant figures. Have you seen graphs where a value will be represented by a point plus error bars? It's the same idea; those error bars represent a certain number of significant figures. It's the "point plus error bars" that has the significant figures, not the thing being measured.

This is a good answer, but I believe you have a small mistake/typo. Without any other details provided, my understanding is that a value of $3.00\times 10^8$ means that it's between $2.995\times 10^{8}$ and $3.005\times 10^{8}$, for a possible error range of $0.01\times 10^{8}=10^{6}$, not $10^{7}$ as in your answer. Alternatively, perhaps you meant to use $3.0\times 10^{8}$ instead.

@JohnOmielan From wikipedia: "Another example involves a volume measurement of 2.98 L with an uncertainty of ± 0.05 L. The actual volume falls between 2.93 L and 3.03 L. Even if certain digits are not completely known, they are still significant if they are meaningful, as they indicate the actual volume within an acceptable range of uncertainty. In this case, the actual volume might be 2.94 L or possibly 3.02 L, so all three digits are considered significant.[1] Thus, there are three significant figures in this example."

Thank you for your feedback. It seems the Wikipedia article you're quoting from is Significant figures. However, note this is not the same thing as I was talking about. In particular, this has an explicitly stated uncertainty, which overrides the implicit default uncertainty value. Note that, in the linked reference of 4.6: Significant Figures and Rounding - Chemistry LibreTexts, ...

(cont.) that paragraph appears to come from the first paragraph in the "Rounding Error" section, about a third of the way down the page. Also, the next paragraph there states "Since only the left most “$3$” in “$3.28$” is certain, you would probably elect to round the value to $3.3$ g. So far, so good. But what is someone else supposed to make of this figure when they see it in your report? The value “$3.3$ g” suggests an implied uncertainty of $3.3\pm 0.05$ g, ...". This is consistent with what I stated. Also, in the "Implied Uncertainty" section just above this, it says ...

(cont.) "Suppose, however, that you are simply told that an object has a length of $0.42$ cm, with no indication of its precision. In this case, all you have to go on is the number of digits contained in the data. Thus the quantity “$0.42$ cm” is specified to $0.01$ unit in $0$ $42$, or one part in $42$". Another example is in the Wikipedia article about the rules, with an example stating "$101.12003$ consists of eight significant figures if the resolution is to $0.00001$" which is, once again, consistent with what I stated. My understanding is that the set of the possible values which a ...

(cont.) stated value with a specific number of significant figures represents are those which round to that stated value with the specific precision using the standard rounding rules. Finally, note there are quite a few related questions about this on Math SE, of which I believe I answered at least one, and possibly two. In particular, there are currently $85$ results tagged [significant-figures] in this list, ...

(cont.) $933$ results with significant figures in this list and, with the term I've mostly heard being used in relation this, $1396$ results with significant digits in this list. Since this is only fairly tangential to what the question is asking, and I've already spent considerable time & effort on this, I won't respond any further about this topic.

If you use Planck Units the problem dissolves. The speed of light is 1. Not 1.0, not 1.00000, but just 1.

If you use SI units, the speed of light is 299792458 m/s. Not 299792458.0 m/s, not 299792458.00000 m/s, but just 299792458 m/s.
