# What is the derivation of the speed of light $c$ that is not based on electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, speed-of-light

The "speed of light" is not just the speed of electromagnetic radiation, but of any massless particle. Therefore must not there be an expression for $c$ that is not in terms of $\mu_0$ and $\epsilon_0$ (and more generally not in terms of electromagnetic quantities such as charge and the fine structure constant)? If not, then what prevents some massless $U(1)^\prime$ field from having $\mu_0^\prime$ and $\epsilon_0^\prime$ that result in a $c^\prime\neq c$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do all massless particles (e.g. photon, graviton, gluon) necessarily have the same speed $c$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90469/)

Comment: Thanks, that is basically the same question, although I'm annoyed at the answers being so qualitative (and I think the top-voted one mentioning virtual particles is terrible). The "Is there a no-go theorem"? question wasn't addressed very directly. Maybe if I leave this up it will have some better luck.

Comment: You can check the following topic for the answer you want to get:
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76492/ .

Comment: There are some other questions about this if you search for "massless particle" and "speed of light", I chose the one as duplicate I thought might best suited for this, but the answer you seek is probably in there somewhere. I've found no answer that would fully satisfy me either, I have to admit. Might be worth it to offer a bounty with "The current answers do not contain enough detail" or somesuch on one of the old ones, though, instead of asking it anew, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @LubosMotl [argued in a blog post](http://motls.blogspot.com/2008/07/bimetric-pseudoscience.html) that a quantum theory with two metrics (hence two light cones) can't be physically consistent.

Comment: The expression is c = 1, i.e. the appearence of c in equations is an artifact of the fact that classical mechanics is a scaling limit of special relativity with c playing the role of the scaling parameter that is sent to infinity. Expressed in SI units, c is a measure of how slow we are compared to our size.

Comment: @Andrew McAddams, thanks. The question itself is trying to do what I was getting at, but unfortunately is tautological (the 'c' in the E-relation could just as well be c-prime in my question). On the other hand I really like Ben Crowell's answer. That's a good no-go argument, although it still leaves me feeling somewhat empty, that there must be a derivation of or expression for c itself that is not tautologically dependent on electromagnetism specifically as an example of a massless field.

Comment: We know the speed of gravitons? When has that been measured?