# What does light travel through or why it is independent of a medium?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, refraction, aether

According to my research and understanding I cant get over the fact that light needs no media to travel, or is it scientifically or mathematically proven?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't electromagnetic waves require a medium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19670/)

Comment: Consider mass can travel with no medium. A rock flies through a vacuum just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Light, or electromagnetic waves, are just that, waves in the background electromagnetic fields. You could argue that they indeed have a medium, the EM field. This is similar to sound, which is pressure waves in a substance. Light is waves in an EM field.

You might have difficulty with this because most waves we normally think of are waves caused by particles of a substance oscillating in position. That is not the case for light. Electric and magnetic fields are not composed of atoms, so when they oscillate we don't require atoms to be present at all. When someone says light has no medium, they mean there is no physical substance composed of atoms that needs to oscillate. We still need a background medium. If there were no background EM fields, there would be no light (a rather trite and unphysical statement for any physicists reading this).

Hope that clears things up

Comment: thanks itll sure help